# Mysql Merge 2 Columns in table but prefer first column value over second

Tags: mysql, merge

I have a two column in my database like:

```
 OMI   |  IUT    |    Final
------------------------------------------------
 98234 |         |   
       |  V3455  |   
 09876 |  V5537  |
```

I have another column "Final" that is empty and I want to merge these two column in the third column like"

```
 OMI   |  IUT    |    Final
------------------------------------------------
 98234 |         |   98234
       |  V3455  |   V3455
 09876 |  V5537  |   09876
```

So basically

if OMI is empty .. take IUT value 
if IUT is empty .. take OMI value 
if both have values, take OMI value

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE tablename SET final=IF(OMI='',IUT,OMI);

Comment: Awesome. Just one little request .. can we create a new column say = "type" and fill the values like this
<br/ >

if OMI is empty .. take IUT value for FINAL and insert IUT in type  ......
if IUT is empty .. take OMI value for FINAL and insert OMI in type .......
if both have values, take OMI value for FiNAL and insert OMI in type ......

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN TYPE varchar(100); UPDATE tablename SET type=IF(OMI='','IUT','OMI');

Comment: if i used concat in update then how write the query @gulam

Comment: So instead of your first answer .. do I just use this sql query and I will get complete result that I am looking for OR this is additional query? If I've to run 2 queries, can you probably help me with one query that does both tasks?

Comment: UPDATE tablename SET final=IF(OMI='',IUT,OMI), type=IF(OMI='','IUT','OMI');

Comment: Brilliant Answer ... You rock!